# Malfunctioning program compiled with gluonfx: build

Tags: java, javafx, gluonfx

I compiled my JAVA program via GluonFX, under Windows, to get a native language version. When the program is running, I get various error messages, such as:
**java.lang.NoSuchMathodException: java.lang.Math.sin (double)**

Below are other errors, when I run mvn gluonfx: nativerun

> [lun nov 29 09:39:00 CET 2021][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK
> ==================== [lun nov 29 09:39:00 CET 2021][FINE] PB Command for run until end:
> C:\Gluon\MathPlaceTest\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\MathPlaceTest.exe
> [lun nov 29 09:39:00 CET 2021][FINE] Start process run until end...
> [lun nov 29 09:39:01 CET 2021][INFO] [SUB] Main [lun nov 29 09:39:01
> CET 2021][INFO] [SUB] Nov 29, 2021 9:39:01 AM
> com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup [lun nov 29 09:39:01
> CET 2021][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration:
> classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @1729ec00' [lun nov 29
> 09:40:58 CET 2021][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "JavaFX Application
> Thread" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javafx.scene.shape.Polyline
>
> [lun nov 29 09:44:45 CET 2021][INFO] [SUB]
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.sun.prism.shader.Solid_TextureRGB_AlphaTest_Loader
>
> [lun nov 29 09:44:46 CET 2021][INFO] [SUB] java.lang.InternalError:
> Error loading stock shader Solid_TextureRGB_AlphaTest [lun nov 29
> 10:41:36 CET 2021][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX
> configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @6d074b14'
> [lun nov 29 10:41:48 CET 2021][INFO] [SUB]
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.sun.prism.shader.Solid_TextureRGB_AlphaTest_Loader

Another problem: a secondary window opens, but it is white.
I believe that there is something wrong or missing in the pom.xml file, which I report here.
I ask for help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
        <charm.version>6.0.6</charm.version>
        <glisten.afterburner.version>2.0.5</glisten.afterburner.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.11</attach.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>1.0.4</gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>
       
        <main.class>com.gluonmathplace.DiMath</main.class>
    </properties>

    <artifactId>DiMath</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.gluonmathplace</groupId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MathPlaceTest</name>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--prova-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
            <classifier>desktop</classifier>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>ble</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>position</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>position</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   
    

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you try again with the latest plugin 1.0.9? Also what’s your GraalVM version?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.8.2 (ea98e05a04480131370aa0c110b8c54cf726c06f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.2
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: C:\GraalVM\graalvm-svm-windows-gluon-21.2.0-dev

Comment: Do you get the same with 1.0.9?

Comment: If you are referring to gluonfx.maven.plugin.version, it is version 1.0.4

Comment: I know, I was asking you to try again with the latest plugin 1.0.9.

Comment: I tried with version 1.0.9 of gluonfx.maven.plugin.version, but everything as before

Comment: Hard to say without more information about your project. Did you try `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before creating the native image with `mvn gluonfx:build`?

Comment: I solved the problem by eliminating the getDeclaredMethod method. Thanks to José